# Как вывести значения Timer в Label

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть у меня игра "Найди пару". Добавил таймер на форму и хочу выводить это время в label.
Типо: "00:01", "00:02", ... "01:01", "01:02".
Только начинаю работать с Windows Forms.

```
 private void TimeTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string time;
            time = timer2.ToString();
            time_text.Text = time;
        }
```

Такой код выводит [System... **че то там**]
Подскажите, что делаю не так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое `timer2`? Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: timer2 - это элемент timer, который добавлен на форму. Создан для того, чтобы считать время, которое игрок провел в игре

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таймер служит для вызова обработчика события с определенным интервалом, он не подходит для измерения времени. Попробуйте [Stopwatch](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8#methods) в дополнение к таймеру.

```cs
private readonly Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    stopwatch.Start(); // запустить секундомер
    // stopwatch.Stop(); // остановить секундомер
    // stopwatch.Restart(); // перезапустить секундомер с нуля
    // stopwatch.Reset(); // остановить и сбросить
}

private void TimeTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    time_text.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("mm\\:ss");
}
```

То есть секундомер считает время, а Timer занимается обновлением значения этого времени на экране.

---

Есть еще [вот такое решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1275283/373567) для продвинутых разработчиков, там секунды можно хоть вручную без секундомера считать.

Comment: Выделят ошибкой "\" в "mm\:ss".
Ошибка: Представляет текст, как последовательность частей из кода UTF-16.

Comment: @NeoShima поправил

Comment: А, всё. Заработало! Спасибо.