# Почему не происходит события для обновления состояния рисования стрелки?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Почему не происходит события для обновления состояния рисования стрелки?

Не будьте слишком строги ко мне, я учусь.

Таймер вызывается в MainWindow.xaml.css

Code Model:

```
public class TimeD
    {
        public double hss { get; set; }
        public double mss { get; set; }
        public double sss { get; set; }
        public void RR()
        {
            DispatcherTimer Timer = new DispatcherTimer
            {
                Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
            };
            Timer.Tick +=Timer_Tick;
            Timer.Start();
            
        }
        public void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            vmClock vmClock = new vmClock();
        }

        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        public double getHss()
        {

            hss = (time.Hour) * (360 / 12);
            return hss;
        }
        public double getMss()
        {

            mss = (time.Minute) * (360 / 60);
            return mss;
        }
        public double getSss()
        {
            sss = (time.Second) * (360 / 60);
            return sss;
        }


    }


}
```

Code ViewModel:

```
public class vmClock : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        TimeD timeD = new TimeD();
        public double angleHour;
        public double angleMin;
        public double angleSec;

        public double AngleHour
        {
            set
            {
                angleHour = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AngleHour");

            }
            get
            {
                return angleHour;
            }
        }

        public vmClock()
        {
    
            AngleHour = timeD.getHss();
            AngleMin = timeD.getMss();
            AngleSec = timeD.getSss();


        }

        public double AngleMin
        {
            set
            {
                angleMin = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AngleMin");
             
            }
            get
            {
                return angleMin;
            }
        }

        public double AngleSec
        {
            set
            {
                angleSec = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AngleSec");

            }
            get
            {
                return angleSec;
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }

    }

}
```

Code XAML:

Вот отрывок, где у меня Binding

```
<RotateTransform Angle="{Binding AngleMin, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

                        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding AngleSec, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Вы каждую секунду создаете `new vmClock()`, это не кажется подозрительным? Покажите, где вы настраиваете `DataContext`.

Comment: Посмотрите внимательней на свой код, что видите? Вот у вас привязка :`{Binding AngleMin`, где свойство `AngleMin`? В классе `vmClock`, ок, а где свойство этого класса? Или, где он задан как `DataContext`? Я лишь вижу `vmClock vmClock = new vmClock();`, то есть создается локальная переменная, с которой ничего не делается. Так о каком обновлении может идти речь, если данных как таковых и нет?

Comment: DataContext у меня в Main
там же таймер 
var mw = new MainWindow
            {

                DataContext = new vmClock()
            };
            mw.Show();
            timeD.RR();

Comment: А ещё почитайте вот это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1275283/373567

Comment: Ну вот и ответ, то что происходит в таймере никак не влияет на привязки. Так как привязки смотрят в один экземпляр класса, а вы работаете каждую секунду с новым экземпляром.

Comment: Как это можно реализовать, не совсем понял, буду очень благодарен)

Comment: Не поняли что? Вот у вас есть в `DataContext` объект, в нем нужные вам данные. Вы вместо того, чтобы менять эти данные, пытаетесь в левом классе, который совершенно не знает про основные ваши данные, создать повторно, **новый** объект класса `vmClock`. Вывод? Вам надо в `TimeD` передать `vmClock` и менять свойства в уже созданном ранее классе. Ну либо обратное - ваш класс `TimeD` пусть содержит событие, которое по тику будет вызываться, а в `vmClock` подписываетесь на него и делаете нужные действия (это даже правильней). И да, УЖАСНЫЕ названия!

Comment: примерно так? 
`vmClock vmClock = new vmClock();
        public void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
            vmClock.AngleHour  = (time.Hour) * (360 / 12);
            vmClock.AngleMin = (time.Minute) * (360 / 60);
            vmClock.AngleSec = (time.Second) * (360 / 60);


        }`
' я его за таймер убрал а в самом таймере уже задаю