# Как сделать асинхронный цикл на WPF в C#

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

Для игрушки (аля симулятор программиста - делаю чисто для себя) хочу создать асинхронный цикл, в котором будут капать деньги, тратится настроение и т.д.

Создал, вот только не могу в textBox записать значения из полей объекта - говорят что они принадлежат другому потоку.

Код класса ниже:

```
namespace Master
{
    public class Hero
    {
        int age;
        int money;
        int health;
        bool alive = true;

        public int Age {
            get { return age; }
            set { age = value; } 
        }
        public int Money {
            get { return money; }
            set
            {
                if (alive) { 
                    this.money = value;
                }
            }
        }
        public int Health
        {
            get { return health; }
            set { health = value; }
        }
        public bool Alive
        {
            get { return alive; }
            set { alive = value; }
        }

        public Hero(int Money)
        {
            this.Money = Money;
        }

        //Методы для взаимодействия с героем
        public void addDamage(int damage)
        {
            if (damage > 0)
            {
                Health -= damage;
            }
        }
        public void addHealth(int healPoints)
        {
            Health += healPoints;
        }
        public void addMoney(int income)
        {
            if ( income > 0 )
            {
                Money += income;
            }
        }
        public void payTaxes(int tax)
        {
            if( tax > 0 )
            {
                Money -= tax;
            }
        }
        

    }
}
```

P.S. Понимаю, вопрос скорее всего глупый, можете кидать помидорами, но сначала ответ дайте))

Comment: А где тут цикл?

Comment: Вот [еще решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1275283/373567), если вам критически важно привязываться к реальному времени.

Comment: Тут цикла нет, ибо в нем как раз и проблема)