# Когда можно использовать async void?

Tags: c#, async-await

У меня есть `async` метод, который вызывается во время возникновения `Elapsed` у `System.Timers.Timer`. Делегат принимает только сигнатуру `void` метода, но как пишут в интернете `async void` это небезопасно, а следовательно надо избегать подобного. Что мне делать в такой ситуации, где я вынужден использовать `async void`?

```
private async void _timer_Elapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    await Check();
}
```

Comment: Как-раз у вас это ок, потому что у вас обработка события. Для обработчиков события только и можно использовать `async void`

Comment: "Что мне делать в такой ситуации, где я вынужден использовать async void?" - не забыть обработать возможное исключение.

Comment: Зачем вообще вам таймер? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257322/373567

Comment: @aepot ну что знаю то и использую, спасибо, гляну!

Comment: Все эти таймеры создавались еще до появления асинхронного программирования, как такового, так что вы смешиваете 2 эпохи, со всеми вытекающими. `async void` - плохо, вы без труда найдете, где почитать, почему именно. И допускается `async void` только когда по-другому никак, а в вашем случае очень даже как. Кстати, даже [так можно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1275283/373567), и этого не умеет ни один таймер. Все таймеры засекают время между концом предыдущего обработчика и началом следующего.