# Уведомить View об изменении значения свойства C# MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, таймер

У меня есть таймер в базовой VM:

```
private DispatcherTimer timer;
protected DispatcherTimer Timer { 
  get => timer;
  set
  { 
     timer = value;
     OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}

private int tickCounter = 5;
public int TickCounter
{
  get { return tickCounter; }
  set { tickCounter = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}

public BaseTrainerViewModel()
{
  Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
  Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1d);
  Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (--TickCounter <= 0)
  {
    Timer.Stop();
   }
}
```

И вот такой код в VM, которая наследуется от базовой VM:

```
public RelayCommand startTimer;
public override RelayCommand StartTimer
{
  get
  {
    return startTimer ?? (startTimer = new RelayCommand(obj =>
      {
        Timer.Start();
      },
      obj=>
      {
        return !Timer.IsEnabled;
       }));
  }
}
```

Где Execute - `Timer.Start();`, а CanExecute - `return !Timer.IsEnabled;`

Эта команда привязывается к кнопке:

```
<Button Content="Старт" Command="{Binding StartTimer}"/>
```

Теперь суть проблемы - когда я нажимаю на кнопку, то таймер запускается и начинается обратный отсчет и кнопка при этом не активна, как и должно быть. Когда таймер останавливается (`if (--TickCounter <= 0) Timer.Stop();`), то по идее кнопка должна стать доступна сразу же после этого, но мне необходимо щелкнуть в любом месте формы для того, чтобы кнопка снова стала доступна. Что мне надо сделать, чтобы кнопка становилась доступна после окончания таймера(ну или другими словами как уведомить кнопку о том, что таймер остановился без щелчка по форме)?

P.S. Пытался сделать отдельное свойство `IsStartTimer` которое бы устанавливалось в `true` при запуске и в `false` при остановке таймера, та же проблема.

P.S.S. Предполагаю, что надо где-то вызвать `OnPropertyChanged`, но не совсем понимаю где.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обновление `CanExecute` происходит посредством вызова обработчика `CanExecuteChanged` у команды. Оно скорее всего у вас привязано к `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` внутри `RelayCommand` (вы не показали, это упущение, поэтому я пытаюсь угадать).

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}
```

`CommandManager` вызывает `RequerySuggested` когда происходит событие ввода, например тык мышкой или ввод с клавиатуры. Но можно вызвать и принудительно.

Вот так:

```
if (--TickCounter <= 0)
{
    Timer.Stop();
    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
}
```

---

Кстати, вам стоит познакомиться с асинхронными программированием, тогда не придется мучать таймеры - [Создание бесконечно повторяющегося метода в c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1257309/373567).

Comment: да, спасибо большое, работает, насчет асинхронного программирования в точку, но я его боюсь :)

Comment: @Pekor https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1275282/373567 вот кстати, загляните сюда еще.