# Курсач на C#, тема - "Разаработка системного планировщика"

Tags: c#, scheduler

Накидал пару форм на WPF, но как реализовать сам планировщик идей почти нет. Была мысль реализовать через потоки или таймер, а саму программу поставить на автозагрузку Windows, чтоб она запускалась при входе в систему и работала на фоне. Но я думаю должен быть способ проще, и если есть возможность то без использования сторонних библиотек. Подскажите, если есть какие то мысли

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: В винде есть планировщик задач, у него есть API. Всё уже написано. Если хочется своих костылей, есть отличный NuGet пакет Quarz.NET, в нем уже все с потоками сделано правильно, берите и пользуйтесь. Без сторонних библиотек (хотя смысла не вижу), можно `async/await` использовать - [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257322/373567), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1275282/373567).