# WPF(MVVM) Хочу услишать ваши рекомендации

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, usercontrol, dependencyproperty

**У меня есть код (логично) , WPF(MVVM) - написал свой UserControll и хочу узнать как можно было б улучшить код. Так как, он написан для MVVM, но вся логика UserControll написана во View. Пожалуйста дайте мне путь для розвития) Знаю что этот код плохой)**

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="ClockUnit.View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ClockUnit.View"
        xmlns:Clocker="clr-namespace:ClockUnit.View.UserControls"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ClockUnit.ViewModel"
        xmlns:convert ="clr-namespace:ClockUnit.View.UserControls.Convert"
        x:Name="MainWindowForm"
        >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>




    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="0 20 0 0">
            <Clocker:ClockUserControl Length="{Binding Path=DataContext.Length, ElementName=MainWindowForm}"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Length , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="30" Margin="0 20" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </StackPanel>
        
        
            
    </Grid>
        
        
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors;


using ClockUnit.ViewModel;

namespace ClockUnit.View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ClockUnit.ViewModel
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            SendMessage = new RelayCommand(Click);
        }
        public void Click()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Click");
        }
        public ICommand SendMessage { get; set; }






        private double length = 30;
        public double Length
        {
            get => length; 
            set
            {
                length = value;
                OnProperyChanged(nameof(length));
            }
        }
        



    }
}
```

**ViewModelBase.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClockUnit.ViewModel
{
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnProperyChanged(string variable)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(variable));
        }
    }
}
```

**RelayCommand.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ClockUnit.ViewModel
{
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        Action _Execute;
        public RelayCommand(Action func)
        {
            _Execute = func;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public virtual bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _Execute?.Invoke();
        }
      
        protected void OnCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

**ClockUserControll.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ClockUnit.View.UserControls.ClockUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ClockUnit.View.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             xmlns:vm ="clr-namespace:ClockUnit.ViewModel"
             >

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:ClockViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    
    
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Width="200" Height="200" x:Name="ClockF" Background="WhiteSmoke" ></Canvas>
    </Grid>
    
    
</UserControl>
```

**ClockUserControll.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using ClockUnit.ViewModel;
using ClockUnit.View.UserControls;
using System.ComponentModel;


namespace ClockUnit.View.UserControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для ClockUserControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ClockUserControl : UserControl 
    {

        public readonly static DependencyProperty LengthKey = DependencyProperty.Register("Length", typeof(double), typeof(ClockUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(90.0));
        public double Length
        {
            get => (double)GetValue(LengthKey);
            set => SetValue(LengthKey, value);
        }
 

        public ClockUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ClockViewModel();
            StartTick();    
        }

        public SolidColorBrush ColorLine { get; set; } = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        public int dx = 100;
        public int time;


        public void InitClock()
        {
            Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
            ellipse.Width = 200;
            ellipse.Height = 200;
            ellipse.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
            ellipse.Fill = Brushes.White;
            ellipse.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            ellipse.StrokeThickness = 2;

            Ellipse point = new Ellipse();
            point.Width = 10;
            point.Height = 10;
            point.Fill = Brushes.Black;
            point.Margin = new Thickness(95, 95, 95, 95);

            ClockF.Children.Add(ellipse);
            ClockF.Children.Add(point);


            ClockF.MouseDown += ReturnColor;

        }
        public async void SecondLine()
        {

            double second = DateTime.Now.Second;


            double angle = (second / 59) * 6.28;

            Line line = new Line();

            line.X1 = dx;
            line.Y1 = dx;


            line.X2 = dx + Length * Math.Sin(angle);
            line.Y2 = dx - Length * Math.Cos(angle);

            line.Stroke = ColorLine;
            line.StrokeThickness = 3;



            line.MouseDown += MouseD;



            ClockF.Children.Add(line);

        }
        public async void Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                ClockF.Children.Clear();
                InitClock();
                SecondLine();

            }


            );

        }
        public void StartTick()
        {

            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
            timer.Tick += Tick;
            timer.Start();

        }
        private void MouseD(object sender , MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ColorLine = Brushes.Red;
            time = e.Timestamp;
        }
        private void ReturnColor(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Timestamp != time && ColorLine != Brushes.Black)
            {
                ColorLine = Brushes.Black;
            }
            
        }



    }
}
```

**ClockViewModel.cs**

```
using ClockUnit.ViewModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClockUnit.ViewModel
{
    public class ClockViewModel: ViewModelBase
    {
    }
}
```

**ТРИГГЕР**

```
<RadioButton 
             Width="1"
             Height="48"
             Background="Black"
             Command="{Binding ArrowClickCommand, ElementName=uc}"
             CommandParameter="Second"
             GroupName="arrow"
             RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1"
             Cursor="Hand"
             Style = "{StaticResource Button.Toggle}"
             >
                       <RadioButton.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding SecondAngle, ElementName=uc}" />
                                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="-24" />
                            </TransformGroup>
                       </RadioButton.RenderTransform>







                <RadioButton.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)">
                                <DoubleAnimation 
                                             To="{Binding SecondAngle, ElementName=uc}"
                                             Duration="0:0:1"  
                                             AutoReverse="False" 
                                             RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </RadioButton.Triggers>
            </RadioButton>
```

Comment: Ну например вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1275282/373567

Comment: aepot спасибо я не знал того. Новое узнал. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, вы правы, код весьма странный.

##### Пройдемся по недостаткам

1. Установка `DataContext` внутри View объекта плохо, ведь тем самым ваш View знает про другие слои, а также (что еще хуже), управляет созданием других слоев. То есть, вот этого у вас быть вообще не должно:

   ```
   <Window.DataContext>
       <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
   </Window.DataContext>
   ```

   как и этого

   ```
   this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
   ```

   На SO есть отличный ответ эту тему, [советую почитать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553).
2. `ClockUserControl` - С именами я думаю вы понимаете, что стоит поработать, к чему тут допустим `UserControl` приписка? Вы у стандартных контролов видите такое? `TextBoxUserControl`, `BorderUserControl`? Я - нет. Так почему вы так городите?
3. У `ClockUserControl` установлен свой `DataContext`, когда он должен быть независимым от чего либо, у него должно быть `DependencyProperty`, которое принимает, к примеру время, все, на основе этих данных он дальше и работает, но внутри него не должно быть каких-либо данных, как и не должно быть указания каких-либо `DataContext`. Вот просто смотрите на стандартные контролы, вы видите у `TextBox` допустим установленного `DataContext`? Да вроде нет.
4. Вы создаете в коде контролы, например это:

   ```
   Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
   ```

   Зачем тогда вы используете WPF проект, в котором есть XAML разметка созданная **специально** для дизайна, не используя ее? Берите WinForms, пишите там по старинке, будет еще более-менее уместно, но в WPF, вы не должны вообще хотеть в коде использовать и создавать контролы, 90% задач спокойно берет на себя чистый XAML.
5. Ваша логика часов весьма странная, ибо вы постоянно добавляете новый контрол (`ClockF.Children.Add(line);`), постоянно перерисовываете все часы целиком, ради того, чтобы просто поменять угол наклона стрелочки. В WPF есть механизмы, которые позволяют задавать угол любому объекту, делается это через `RotateTransform`, просто установите его, привяжите свойство `Angle` и меняйте просто привязанное свойство, чтобы подвинуть стрелку, все.

Теперь давайте попробуем сделать как положено:

##### Создадим контрол

**Цель** - сделать контрол, который на вход будет принимать объект времени (в C# это `TimeSpan`) и на его основе просто ставить стрелки в нужном положении.

1. Создаем `UserControl`, назовем просто `Clock`.
2. Теперь давайте создадим просто равномерный круг, который будет подстраиваться под размеры контейнера:

   ```
    <Viewbox
        MinHeight="100"
        Stretch="Uniform"
        StretchDirection="Both">
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse
                Width="100"
                Height="100"
                Fill="WhiteSmoke"
                Stroke="Silver"
                StrokeThickness=".5" />
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
   ```

   `Viewbox` - автоматически подгоняет внутренние объекты под размеры контейнера, свойства у него заданы такие, чтобы при изменении размера менялись все стороны пропорционально, а само содержимое заполняло полностью весь контейнер. Внутри простая сетка с кругом, у которого лишь заданы цвета.
3. Теперь давайте сделаем три стрелки (час, мин, сек), получим полностью примерно следующее:

   ```
    <Viewbox
        MinHeight="100"
        Stretch="Uniform"
        StretchDirection="Both">
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse
                Width="100"
                Height="100"
                Fill="WhiteSmoke"
                Stroke="Silver"
                StrokeThickness=".5" />
            <Line
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                RenderTransformOrigin="0,1"
                Stroke="#FF4C4C4C"
                StrokeThickness="2"
                Y2="40">
                <Line.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="30" />
                        <TranslateTransform X="0.5" Y="-20" />
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Line.RenderTransform>
            </Line>
            <Line
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                RenderTransformOrigin="0,1"
                Stroke="#FF4C4C4C"
                StrokeThickness="2"
                Y2="30">
                <Line.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                        <TranslateTransform X="0.5" Y="-15" />
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Line.RenderTransform>
            </Line>
            <Line
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                RenderTransformOrigin="0,1"
                Stroke="Black"
                StrokeThickness=".5"
                Y2="48">
                <Line.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="60" />
                        <TranslateTransform X=".13" Y="-24" />
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Line.RenderTransform>
            </Line>
            <Ellipse
                Width="5"
                Height="5"
                Fill="Silver" />
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
   ```

   Тут у нас простые линии, определенной длины, определенного цвета. У каждой линии есть `RenderTransform` - это настройки трансформации, где `RotateTransform` - поворот на указанный угол относительно центральной точки, а `TranslateTransform` - сдвиг объекта по оси X/Y. Сама центральная точка задается свойством `RenderTransformOrigin`, конкретно в коде выше, это низ объекта, по центру.

На данном моменте у нас получается нечто такое:

[image: ClockResult]

4. Теперь давайте автоматизировать это все. Как я писал ранее, на вход контрол будет принимать только `TimeSpan` (вы можете по аналогии вынести все цвета, ну и другие значения). Идем в `Clock.xaml.cs`, пишем после конструктора `propdp` и жмем два раза `TAB`, студия нам создаст код, в котором нам надо указать тип контрола, тип свойства, ну и значение по умолчанию. Получаем такое:

   ```
    public TimeSpan Time
    {
        get => (TimeSpan)GetValue(TimeProperty);
        set => SetValue(TimeProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TimeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Time", typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(Clock), new PropertyMetadata(TimeSpan.Zero));
   ```
5. Отлично, теперь мы знаем время, осталось немного, а именно, подсчитать градусы для стрелок и привязать их. Давайте по каждому изменению свойства времени, будем вызывать определенный метод. В `DependencyProperty` можно это сделать путем указания самого метода после значения по умолчанию (`TimeSpan.Zero`), ну а так, как свойство статично, нам надо проверить `sender` события, преобразовать его, а уже затем вызывать метод. Получим примерно следующее:

   ```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TimeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Time", typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(Clock), new PropertyMetadata(TimeSpan.Zero, OntPropertyChanged));


    private static void OntPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Clock clock)
        {
            clock.UpdateAngles();
        }
    }

    public void UpdateAngles()
    {

    }
   ```
6. Сделаем теперь публичные свойства, которые будут содержать в себе угол каждой стрелки, ну и посчитаем их:

   ```
    public double HourAngle { get; private set; }
    public double MinuteAngle { get; private set; }
    public double SecondAngle { get; private set; }

    public void UpdateAngles()
    {
        // В помощь: https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/clock-angle

        var totalHours = 12;                                             // Сколько часов в одном круге
        var totalMinutes = 60;                                           // Сколько минут в одном круге
        var totalAngle = 360;                                            // Полная окружность
        double hourAnglePerHour = totalAngle / totalHours;               // На сколько градусов меняется угол часовой стрелки в час = 30
        double hourAnglePerMin = hourAnglePerHour / totalMinutes;        // На сколько градусов меняется угол часовой стрелки в мин = 0.5
        double minAndSecAnglePerMin = totalAngle / totalMinutes;         // На сколько градусов меняется угол мин. и сек. за минуту = 6

        HourAngle = hourAnglePerHour * Time.Hours + hourAnglePerMin * Time.Minutes;

        MinuteAngle = Time.Minutes * minAndSecAnglePerMin;
        SecondAngle = Time.Seconds * minAndSecAnglePerMin;

        OnProperyChanged(nameof(HourAngle));
        OnProperyChanged(nameof(MinuteAngle));
        OnProperyChanged(nameof(SecondAngle));
    }
   ```

   `OnProperyChanged` - это INPC, с которым вы уже знакомы, я поленился делать отдельный класс, запихнул это прям в контрол и вызвал в методе. Вам советую вынести это в сами свойства. Со всеми подсчетами думаю разберетесь, я оставил ссылку, где отлично объясняют как посчитать углы.
7. Теперь открываем XAML контрола, задаем самому контролу имя `x:Name="uc"`, далее привязываем угол каждой стрелки к своему свойству примерно следующим образом:

   ```
    <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding MinuteAngle, ElementName=uc}" />
   ```
8. Контрол наш готов, использовать его так:

   ```
    <local:Clock Time="23:40:15" />
   ```

Результат:

[image: Static Clock Result]

##### Привязываем к реальному времени

Давайте запустим фоновую задачу, которая просто будет менять значение свойства, к которому мы привяжемся.

1. Делаем класс, например `MainViewModel`, в нем пишем следующее:

   ```
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Start();
        }

        private TimeSpan _time;

        public TimeSpan Time
        {
            get => _time;
            set
            {
                _time = value;
                OnProperyChanged(nameof(Time));
            }
        }


        public async void Start()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnProperyChanged(string variable)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(variable));
        }
    }
   ```

   INPC лучше вынести в отдельный класс (как у вас в вопросе), я просто ленюсь... По коду думаю ничего сложного нет, простая фоновая (`async`) задача, которая крутит бесконечный цикл, в котором раз секунду меняется свойство времени. Учтите, `async void` не лучшая затея, если вы будете там писать серьезный код, который надо ожидать и который может выдать ошибки, у меня как видите просто меняется свойство, без какой-либо логики, из-за чего такой подход тут вполне подойдет. Также не забывайте про остановку, если она нужна, то смотрите в сторону `CancellationToken`.
2. Открываем `App.xaml` и убираем там `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"`.
3. Открываем `App.xaml.cs` и переопределяем там `OnStartup` на нечто такое:

   ```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        new MainWindow() { DataContext = new MainViewModel() }.Show();
    }
   ```
4. Открываем `MainWindow.xaml` и прописываем там наш контрол:

   ```
    <local:Clock Time="{Binding Time}" />
   ```

   Как видите, через `Binding` мы привязались к свойству, которое отдает нам текущее время.

Результат всей этой работы, следующий:

[image: Total Result]

Собственно, вот мы и сделали контрол, который на основе входного времени показывает его в виде аналоговых часов. Заметьте, контрол не знает ничего про ViewModel слои, он независим вообще от чего либо, а само время у нас в ViewModel слое (если время получается из вне, то должно быть в Model). Так что, старайтесь делить все на мало связанные друг с другом слои, это основы основ MVVM)

---

##### Дополнение №1: Кликабельные стрелки.

1. Из за того, что нам надо убирать выделение с других стрелок при клике на определенную, нам надо использовать `RadioButton`, который позволяет задать имя группы, по которому он сам будет убирать выделение. Но стандартный `RadioButton` является просто кругом с точной, что не очень подходит под задачу, придется писать стиль. Сам стиль можем разместить где угодно, хоть в ресурсах приложения, хоть в ресурсах контрола, хоть в ресурсах самих стрелок, разметка будет примерно следующей:

   ```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style
            x:Key="Button.Toggle"
            BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"
            TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Border
                            x:Name="border"
                            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
   ```

   Как видите, я поместил стиль в ресурсы самого контрола. Сам стиль наследуется от `ToggleButton`, чтобы по поведению был как простая кнопка, ну а внутри я меняю вид на простой `Border`. Также тут интересен триггер, который меняет цвет стрелки, если по ней нажать.
2. Теперь нам нужно еще одно `DependencyProperty`, которое будет принимать `ICommand` - команду, по клику которой мы будем делать в VM нужные нам действия:

   ```
    public ICommand ArrowClickCommand
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(ArrowClickCommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(ArrowClickCommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ArrowClickCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ArrowClickCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(Clock), new PropertyMetadata(null));
   ```
3. Имея команду и стиль, мы можем теперь переделать все стрелки на `RadioButton`, с указанием сразу команды и ее параметров:

   ```
    <RadioButton
        Width=".5"
        Height="48"
        Background="Black"
        Command="{Binding ArrowClickCommand, ElementName=uc}"
        CommandParameter="second"
        GroupName="arrow"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1"
        Style="{StaticResource Button.Toggle}">
        <RadioButton.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding SecondAngle, ElementName=uc}" />
                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="-24" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </RadioButton.RenderTransform>
    </RadioButton>
   ```

   Я не стал приводить все стрелки, лишь секундную, отличия тут минимальные, лишь поменяли `Line` на `RadioButton`. Из нового тут `GroupName` - расказывал выше про это; `Command` - ранее созданная команда; `CommandParameter` - передаваемые в команду значения (в мое случае просто строковое обозначение кнопки).
4. С контролом мы закончили, осталось сделать команду в VM слое. Ваш класс `RelayCommand` я заменю на такой:

   ```
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> execute;
        private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
        {
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return canExecute == null || canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            execute(parameter);
        }
    }
   ```
5. Дальшее в `MainViewModel` делаем публичное свойство команды

   ```
    public ICommand ArrowClickCommand { get; set; }
   ```
6. Инициализируем эту команду в конструкторе:

   ```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Start();
        ArrowClickCommand = new RelayCommand(param => OnArrowClick(param));
    }
   ```
7. Ну и сам метод. Я его реализовывать не буду, оставлю это вам, я лишь сделаю заглушку, которая в отладочную консоль будет выводить тег стрелки:

   ```
    private void OnArrowClick(object arrow)
    {
        if (arrow is string arrowKey)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(arrowKey);
        }
    }
   ```

Все, теперь при клике должна выделяться одна конкретная стрелка и вызываться команда, которая уже сделает все необходимые действия.

##### Дополнение №2: Анимация.

1. Для начала давайте сделаем событие, которое будет оповещать нас о том, что у нас изменилось время, для этого в C# коде создаем само событие:

   ```
    public static readonly RoutedEvent ClockChangedEvent
    = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ClockChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(Clock));

    public event RoutedEventHandler ClockChanged
    {
        add => AddHandler(ClockChangedEvent, value);
        remove => RemoveHandler(ClockChangedEvent, value);
    }
   ```
2. Теперь идем в XAML и находим там нашу секундную стрелку, нам надо задать ей имя (`x:Name="..."`), а также прописать саму анимацию, получить должны примерно следующее:

   ```
    <RadioButton
        x:Name="SecondArrow"
        Width=".5"
        Height="48"
        Background="Black"
        Command="{Binding ArrowClickCommand, ElementName=uc}"
        CommandParameter="second"
        GroupName="arrow"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1"
        Style="{StaticResource Button.Toggle}">
        <RadioButton.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="-24" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </RadioButton.RenderTransform>
        <RadioButton.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:Clock.ClockChanged">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            AutoReverse="False"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                            From="{Binding OldSecondAngle, ElementName=uc}"
                            To="{Binding SecondAngle, ElementName=uc}"
                            Duration="0:0:1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </RadioButton.Triggers>
    </RadioButton>
   ```

   Заметьте, привязки я перенес в саму анимацию, а также добавил новую `{Binding OldSecondAngle, ElementName=uc}` о которой позже. Сама анимация очень простая - мы ищем нужное свойство и плавно меняем с одного значения на другое в течении 1 сек.
3. Имея все это давайте подправим метод `UpdateAngles`, изменим на примерно следующий:

   ```
    public double OldSecondAngle { get; private set; }

    public void UpdateAngles()
    {
        // В помощь: https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/clock-angle

        OldSecondAngle = SecondAngle;

        var totalHours = 12;                                          // Сколько часов в одном круге
        var totalMinutes = 60;                                        // Сколько минут в одном круге
        var totalAngle = 360;                                         // Полная окружность
        double hourAnglePerHour = totalAngle / totalHours;               // На сколько градусов меняется угол часовой стрелки в час = 30
        double hourAnglePerMin = hourAnglePerHour / totalMinutes;        // На сколько градусов меняется угол часовой стрелки в час = 0.5
        double minAndSecAnglePerMin = totalAngle / totalMinutes;         // На сколько градусов меняется угол мин. и сек. за минуту = 6

        HourAngle = hourAnglePerHour * Time.Hours + hourAnglePerMin * Time.Minutes;

        MinuteAngle = Time.Minutes * minAndSecAnglePerMin;
        SecondAngle = Time.Seconds * minAndSecAnglePerMin;

        if (OldSecondAngle > 360) OldSecondAngle -= 360;
        if (SecondAngle == 0 || OldSecondAngle == 360) SecondAngle += 360;

        OnProperyChanged(nameof(HourAngle));
        OnProperyChanged(nameof(MinuteAngle));
        OnProperyChanged(nameof(SecondAngle));
        OnProperyChanged(nameof(OldSecondAngle));

        SecondArrow.RaiseEvent(new (ClockChangedEvent, this));
    }
   ```

   Тут как видите, появилось новое свойство, которое хранит в себе предыдущий угол стрелки. `SecondArrow.RaiseEvent(...)` - мы именно у нашей стрелки вызываем событие. Ну и всякие `if (OldSecondAngle > 360)` - это для того, чтобы анимация после полного круга не крутила стрелку обратно, ибо новый градус будет 0, а старый 360, из за чего нам надо чуть "протолкнуть" стрелку дальше на пару градусов (366 например) и уже после этого анимации задать `From` как `6` (старый градус), а `To` (новый градус) как 12, тем самым стрелка пойдет дальше делать круг.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137979/discussion-on-answer-by-evgeniyz-wpfmvvm----).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , спасибо за Дополнение №2: Анимация.