# Как правильно получать дату в c#?

Tags: c#

В своей программе я получаю дату через DateTime.Today/DateTime.Now, но если программа висит без перезапуска больше суток, то у нее не меняется число дня. То есть если в момент запуска было 01.11.2022, то через сутки почему-то остается так же.

Мне нужно самому отслеживать время когда день закончился и добавлять или как?

Мой код:

```
public static string todayDate = $"{DateTime.Now.Day}.{DateTime.Now.Month}.{DateTime.Now.Year}";
```

Я конечно понимаю что правильно будет через DateOnly получать. Но вот просто вот так получаю дату, И например по команде /start в боте мне выводится дата. Каждый день по идее должна быть разная дата.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1257309/373567

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1275282/373567

Comment: И нельзя текущую дату/время несколько раз подряд запрашивать.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну почему же, операционка стерпит, но это конечно же неэффективно

Comment: @aepot, потому что, например, когда она изменится, у тебя будет год и месяц вчерашние, а число - сегодняшнее.

Comment: А где вы отображаете эту дату или как используете? Какой тип приложения?

Comment: Можно таймер завести, который в полночь будет менять значение.

Comment: Нашел четкое решение через `System.Management` https://stackoverflow.com/a/295252/12888024 если будет непонятно, оформлю ответом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по коду, вы инициализируете строку при старте приложения, после чего её содержимое не меняется. Вместо этого вам нужно в явном виде запрашивать `DateTime.Now` каждый раз.

Можно сделать чуть проще, чем в вашем коде, используя выражение `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")`. Но не сохраняйте его в переменной, а каждый раз обращайтесь к этому выражению, тогда дата будет всегда актуальная.

Comment: Я пробовал, до перезапуска приложения дата не меняется.

Comment: @АртёмДадашьянц так сделайте цикл, который будет ее обновлять раз в минуту или даже раз в секунду. Я бы дал ответ, но вы ни в какую не показываете код и не объясняете, где она не обновляется, как вы туда ее записываете и зачем она нужна.