# Как правильно реализовать ожидание в цикле? Консольное приложение метроном,

Tags: c#, циклы

недавно начал изучать C# и программирование в целом. Хочу сделать в качестве учебного проекта метроном в консольном приложении, постепенно добавляя новые функции.

На первом этапе хочу сделать проигрывание звука метронома с заданной скоростью и возможностью в реальном времени убавлять\прибавлять темп клавишами - +, и ставить на паузу и продолжать работу при нажатии пробела в зависимости от текущего состояния метронома. Точность таймера пока непринципиальна. Для проигрывания звука использую System.Timers

Выглядит черновик выглядит примерно так:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Metronome metronome = new Metronome();
            metronome.Start();
                      
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
      }

public class Metronome
{
    private SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
    private Timer playerTimer = new Timer();

    private int bpm = 120;
    private int interval;
    private bool isRunning = true;

    public Metronome()
    {
        playerTimer.Elapsed += OnTimeElapsed;
        playerTimer.Interval = 60000 / bpm;
    }

    private void OnTimeElapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        player.Play();
        Console.WriteLine("Sound is played, add sound path later");          
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        while (isRunning)
        {
            playerTimer.Start();
        }
    }

    private void Pause()
    {
        //Pause
    }

    private void UnPause()
    {
        //Unpause
    }
}
```

Возник вопрос, чтобы не загружать процессор имитацией полезной цикла во время ожидания нажатия клавиши, хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы проверка на ввод проводилась 60 раз в секунду.

Подскажите какими способами можно сделать? Из знакомых для меня это пока Sleep и еще один таймер.

Про Sleep читал, что его не следует использовать, особенно, если добавить графический интерфейс. С таймером получается немного запутанный код.

Интересует какими методами сейчас реализуются в приложениях подобные ограничения, когда максимальная скорость выполнения цикла не нужна, а требуется минимально необходимое использование процессора?

Спасибо.

Comment: Асинхронность с `Task.Delay()` в помощь.

Comment: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1275282/373567), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257322/373567). Здесь главная проблема в том, что ни `Thread.Sleep(x)`, не `await Task.Delay(x)` вам не дадут точных временных отсечек, будет отклонение в бОльшую сторону. У Sleep поменьше, у Delay побольше. Подсказка в ответе по первой ссылке.

Comment: 1 - ReadKey не нагружает процессор. 2 -  цикл не нужен: таймер запускается 1 раз. Главное, чтобы AutoReset стоял.

Comment: @aepot спасибо. Точность пока не принципиальна, поскольку сам метроном, является эталонными часами. Если конечно, его сравнивать с другими часами то погрешность станет заметна, но пока это не важно. Мне важно понять, какие есть хорошие практики того как можно ограничить цикл while(true). Насколько я читал информацию, что он максимально использует ресурсы процессора. То есть мне нужно, проверять с частотой 60 раз в секунду, был ли нажат пробел.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо.

Comment: _хочу ... убавлять\прибавлять темп клавишами ... ставить на паузу и продолжать работу_ - это уже сделано? Покажите код. Или проблема как раз в реализации этого? А вовсе не в таймере?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Это пока не сделано, но проблема не в реализации этих функций, я примерно знаю как это сделать. Вопрос был в том, какими способами делают минимальное использование ресурсов, чтобы к примеру проверка буфера клавиатуры выполнялась лишь несколько раз в секунду. К примеру, как запускаете пустую WinForms, она висит и берет лишь самый минимум. (кроме Thread.Sleep)

Comment: `Console.KeyAvailable` и `Console.ReadKey` достаточно для решения задачи.